# How to access a control from ICommand Execute() in ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to implement my first wpf project using ICommand interface. I'd like to unselect all the items in a listbox when user click a reset button. But I don't know how I can access the listbox from ICommand in viewmodel. I am using DelegateCommand pattern for ICommand. It shows the message, but can't access AbsenseCodeListbox. So what is the way to do that? Thanks.

```
    <Button Content="Reset"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,10,20,5" Command="{Binding AbsenceResetCommand}"/>
...

    <ListBox Name="AbsenseCodeListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding absenseCodeItems, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="20,0,20,5" >
    </ListBox>
```

The code in my viewmodel:

```
void AbsenceResetCommand_Execute(object arg)
{
    MessageBox.Show("_AbsenceResetCommand command");
    AbsenseCodeListbox.UnselectAll();//Can't do this way

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to access the control. You should bind the [IsSelected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem.isselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property of a ListBoxItem to an IsSelected property on your absenceCodeItem (add this or make a wrapper class if it makes more sense to do so). Then you just reference the absenceCodeItems in your ViewModel and set their IsSelected property to false.

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="AbsenseCodeListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding absenseCodeItems, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="20,0,20,5" >
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Command:

```
void AbsenceResetCommand_Execute(object arg)
{
   MessageBox.Show("_AbsenceResetCommand command");
   Foreach (var absenseCodeItem in absenseCodeItems)
      absenseCodeItem.IsSelected = false;
}
```

You will run into some issues with selection synchronization due to UI Virtualization so here are some links to a 3 part series showing a more complete implementation: [Part 1](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-i.html), [Part 2](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-ii.html), [Part 3](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html).

Comment: Thanks for letting know this way.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, your view model object has a public property of type `ObservableCollection`, which you data bind to the `ListBox` control's `ItemsSource` property in the XAML.

What you could do is add another property to the view model called `SelectedItems` which is also an `ObservalbeCollection`.  You would bind this property to the `ListBox' SelectedItems` property with a 2 way binding.  Then, to clear the selected items in the `ListBox`, you would just clear the `SelectedItems` collection:

```
void AbsenceResetCommand_Execute(object arg)
{
    SelectedItems.Clear(();
}
```

Comment: That wouldn't unselect the items...it would remove them from the ListBox.

Comment: You're right.  I changed my answer to add another property bound to the `ListBox's SelectedItems` property that could be cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass listbox in command parameter like this

```
 <Button CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AbsenseCodeListbox}" Content="Reset"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,10,20,5" Command="{Binding AbsenceResetCommand}"/>
 <ListBox Name="AbsenseCodeListbox" ItemsSource="{Binding absenseCodeItems, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="20,0,20,5" >
 </ListBox>
```

and viewmodel will become

```
   void AbsenceResetCommand_Execute(object arg)
    {
        ListBox tempListBox = arg as ListBox;

        if (tempListBox != null)
            tempListBox.UnselectAll();
    }
```